# How do you compare the strength of predictor variables?

Tags: survival, cox-model, aic, predictor

We have been assessing the prognostic utility of MRI markers in a patient population. I identified markers-of-interest based on Cox regression analysis. Each marker had aHR of 5.5, 3.7, 2.8, etc, which were adjusted for the same co-variates (ie. age, sex,...) run separately. I ran a collinearity test, and they are co-linear. To clarify, each marker-of-interest was not included as covariates in the next model. My first question is, can we compare aHR of these markers?

If the answer is no, which I assume it is because they are separate models, then my follow-up question is how can we rank the predictor variables in terms of strength. To my understanding determining the AIC of each marker-of-interest can be a way to compare variables. I figured out the AIC of each marker-of-interest and they were 166.41, 140.17, 139.17, etc. Can I simply make a bar graph to show the AIC of each marker and say the lowest one is the strongest?

I am fairly new to statistics and a lot of literature on statistics is going over my head. I feel like I have made a lot of assumptions along the way, so I would love to know if my methodology is correct or if I need to adjust it. I use SPSS, so if I do need to make adjustments, then please explain how I can go about it.

Comment: There are reliable ways to evaluate potential biomarkers, but much depends on the details of your data sample. How many patients were involved, and how many "events" were in your Cox models? How many markers did you have to evaluate? How did you choose among them for a small set of "markers-of-interest"? Please provide that information by editing your question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.